# Binomial Random Variable with unknown probability $p$, with the condition $P\left( |X-E(X)|\le 3 \right)=1$. How to find range of $p$

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I am struggling with this questions on Binomial Random Variable that requires to find the **range of parameter** $p$.

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $(5, p)$. Find the range of $p$ for which
$P\left( |X-E(X)|\le 3 \right)=1$.

Unable to use the relation $P\left( |X-E(X)|\le 3 \right)=1$.

My approach is, to assume  $|X-E(X)|\le 3$ to true as probability of the same  is given as $1$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks @C-RAM! Edited.

Comment: You can approach by finding $E(X)$ in terms of $5$ and $p$. Then you can find the maximal values of $|X-E(X)|$. Finally, you can find what values of $p$ 'work'

Answer (score 1):

Given that $P\left( |X-E(X)|\,\le 3 \right)=1$, that means it is definite event and $|X-E(X)|=1$

Since $E(X)=np=5p$

$\Rightarrow \,|X-np|\,\le 3$

Since $X$ is a Random Binomial Variable with parameters $(5,\,p)$, the value of $X$varies from $0$ to $5$. And absolute difference of $X$ and $np$ should be less than or equal to $3$. So $np$ can be within the shaded portion of the line shown below so that its absolute difference from $X$never exceeds $3$.

[image: Binomial Distribution range]

So, $2\le np\le 3$

$\Rightarrow \frac{2}{3}\le p\le \frac{3}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

As $X$ ~ $B(5, p)$, $E[X] = 5p$

$
\displaystyle
\begin{align}
P(|X-E[X]| \leq 3) &= P(|X-5p| \leq 3)    \\
                   &= P(-3 \leq X-5p \leq 3) \\
                   &= P(5p-3 \leq X \leq 5p+3) \\
                   &= 1
\end{align}
$

It means that every $X$ is in $[5p-3, 5p+3]$

We know that, $X$ varies from $0$ to $5$.

Thus, we get

$
\begin{cases}
5p-3 \leq 0\\
5p+3 \geq 5
\end{cases}
$

which implies $\displaystyle\frac{2}{5} \leq p \leq \frac{3}{5}$